# Vertical align inheritance in CSS

Tags: html, css

I was just going through [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align) of vertical alignment and there are quite a few threads on SO that help understand about vertical alignment. But I have a very basic difficulty.

It says vertical alignment is not inherited, yet when I made a practical demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/49jr9yLs/), vertical alignment is actually being inherited.

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href=""><span>hello</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>hello</span></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><span>hello</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: red;
    color: #fff;
    height: 300px;
    display: table;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul li {
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*display: inline-block;*/
}
```

See how I have added `vertical-align: middle` to `li` yet `span` inherits the vertical alignment. Seeing this it's hard to prove to myself or believe that vertical alignment is **not inheritable**. Can somebody help me understand this paradox?

Comment: the initial value for vertical-align is baseline and if you vertical align the li then the inside elements will sit on the baseline for that li (if they are inline or inline-block, such as span)

Comment: @kolsyrad , i think your right !

Comment: I can post this as the answer if you feel it helped you

Comment: @kolsyrad sure go ahead :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The initial value for `vertical-align` is `baseline` and if you vertical align the `li` then the inside elements will sit on the `baseline` for that `li`.